# Put using Hbase REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, curl, hbase

I am using Hbase REST(Stargate) for putting data into hbase but after inserting a record in hbase , it is inserting extra newline character after each key.

Here is my command for inserting data into Hbase through.

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"Row":[{"key":"cm93Mgo=", "Cell":[{"column":"Y29sZmFtMTpjb2wzCg==", "$":"eyJFbXBsb3llZSI6eyJFbmFtZSI6IlNhbSIsIkVpZCI6MTJ9fQo="}]}]}' http://hostname:8080/testtable/row2/colfam1:col3
```

When i did a scan for hbase testtable , i got follwing output.

```
hbase(main):009:0> scan 'testtable'
ROW                                    COLUMN+CELL
 row2                                  column=colfam1:col1, timestamp=1438063811000, value=shashi
 row2\x0A                              column=colfam1:col3\x0A, timestamp=1438068118825, value={"Employee":{"Ename":"Sam","Eid":12}}\x0A
 row2\x0A                              column=colfam1:col4\x0A, timestamp=1438068118825, value=file4\x0A
3 row(s) in 0.0280 seconds
```

Extra \x0A is getting added after each row key.

Any help here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573506/hbase-rest-call-getting-junk-characters-x0a

Comment: Thanks Vijay...I got the issue...it helped...